# Windows partition not recognized

Tags: 11.04, installation

Using Windows 7 64bit, Installing Ubuntu 11.04 64bit

When trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 on an existing Windows installation I am not able to see my existing partitions not in the installation menu and not in gparted via live cd as well.

sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf5d517a7

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2   *          13      230453  1851010048    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3          230453      236828    51200000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4          236828      243202    51200000    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5          236828      243202    51198976    7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.8 GB, 15812526080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1922 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x34dd3d50

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        1923    15441888+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2            1923        1923          31+  21  Unknown
```

Is this cause of HPFS? How can I resolve it?

EDIT:

```
sudo parted -l
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

I try using [Fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html). There seems to be a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/798285) on this issue but no solution there as well.

Comment: Does `sudo parted -l` give you any faults? Add the output to the question please.

Answer (score 1):

from OP edit:

`sudo -lu` indicated old GPT Data. Fixparts was able to remove them. Now Gparted is able to recognize all partitions.